# Can't update an xml field in a column of a database

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an existing xml field. I want to update the field using Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio. I know of the modify function with replace but it is not working as I wish. I'm using the following link for reference and I've mimicked it but it just creates it's own xml values.

Maybe this even helps, I have a database. In the database I have columns a,b,c. In column c is an xml file. I want to update the the fields of the xml file in column c.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx

```
 declare @a xml

 select @a = convert(xml,[example]).value(
 '(/root/x/y)[1]', 'varchar(5)') 
 from --
 left join -- on -- = --
 where 1=1 and -- = -- and -- = --

 --update rev.REV_SECURITY_DEFAULT
 set @a.modify('
 replace value of (/root/x/@y)[1]
 with "0"')
 select @a

 --new
 SET @a = '<Root>
 <x LocationID="10">
  <y>Manufacturing step 1 at this work center</y>
  </x>
 </Root>'
 SELECT @myDoc
 --update rev.REV_SECURITY_DEFAULT
 set @a.modify('
 replace value of (/root/x/@y)[1]
 with "0"')
 select @a

--UPDATE

select NAME, NAMESPACE, ---
from --
left join -- on -- = --
where 1=1 and --.NAMESPACE = '--' and--.name = '--' 
go

DECLARE @a xml = N'<root><x y="2"/></root>';
SELECT @a;

SET @a.modify('replace value of (/root/x/@y)[1] with "42"');
SELECT @a;
```

new problem when trying to cast the ntext to xml. It doesn't cast it and still gives me `cannot call methods on ntext`

```
SELECT CAST(a.column_name AS XML)
from a

update a

set a.modify('replace value of (/x/y/@z)[1] with "0"')
```

now I need to insert an element into the xml file. I try the following but get an error of "Syntax error near ')', expected a step expression".

```
update #tmp set permissions.modify('insert <EXAMPLE></EXAMPLE> into (/SECURITY/)[1]')
```

Comment: Well, you kinda gotta post an example of your sql that is not working, otherwise no one can help you. `modify` works if done correctly. It is a bit tricky, so no shame in not getting right the first time.

Comment: @mdisibio there ya go

Comment: "It is not working as I wish" - how so ? Also post the content of @a before and after modify

Comment: So, I see two problems, so lets clarify the example before I post an answer: 1) you've set @a to a varchar(5), not to an xml snippet...you are calling `modify` on something that is not inherently xml; and 2), you're first query is `/root/x/y` meaning 'y' is an element, whereas your `modify` query treats y as an attribute...

Comment: So let me clarify one thing...because you declare @a as xml, your are getting an xml fragment, so the modify statement does not throw an error, but because you chain the `.value` statement to the SELECT, you are getting a varchar(5) cast as xml....it is just text, there are no elements...so any `modify` you perform is going to result in either no modification, or something undetermined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After correctly setting the value of @a to be an xml fragment, not a value, if y is an attribute, your syntax would be similar to:

```
DECLARE @a xml = N'<root><x y="2"/></root>';
SELECT @a;

SET @a.modify('replace value of (/root/x/@y)[1] with "42"');
SELECT @a;
```

yields `<root><x y="42"/></root>`

If y is an element your syntax would be:

```
DECLARE @a xml = N'<root><x><y>hello</y></x></root>';
SELECT @a;

SET @a.modify('replace value of (/root/x/y/text())[1] with "world"');
SELECT @a;
```

yields `<root><x><y>world</y></x></root>`

Applying this to a table, here is sample code that will run as is:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(NS varchar(32), NM varchar(16), DocXml xml)
INSERT INTO @T 
  VALUES ('MyNamespace1', 'MyName1', N'<root><x y="2"/></root>'),
         ('MyNamespace2', 'MyName2', N'<root><x y="2"/></root>')

UPDATE @T SET DocXml.modify('replace value of (/root/x/@y)[1] with "42"')
 WHERE NS = 'MyNamespace1' AND NM = 'MyName1';

SELECT * FROM @T
```

However, if the 'xml' column is a text column with xml data and not typed as xml, you cannot both cast to xml and call `modify` in one update statement. You ought to consider either altering the table column to the xml type, or adding an xml column.

Here would be one workaround, assuming your original table has a unique Id:

```
-- represents original table...
CREATE TABLE T(Id int, NS varchar(32), NM varchar(16), DocXml ntext)
INSERT INTO T 
  VALUES (1, 'MyNamespace1', 'MyName1', N'<root><x y="2"/></root>'),
         (2, 'MyNamespace2', 'MyName2', N'<root><x y="2"/></root>');

-- select target records into tempdb
SELECT Id, CAST(DocXml AS xml) AS DocXml INTO #tmp FROM T WHERE NS = 'MyNamespace1' AND NM = 'MyName1';

-- update tempdb
UPDATE #tmp SET DocXml.modify('replace value of (/root/x/@y)[1] with "42"');

-- and copy back to original table
    UPDATE T
       SET DocXml = CAST(U.DocXml AS nvarchar(MAX))
      FROM dbo.T TT
INNER JOIN #tmp U ON TT.Id = U.Id

SELECT * FROM T
```

Comment: Look at my updated post. What is happening is it creates a new xml field with the desired set. However, I want to replace the existing xml field, not create a new one.

Comment: The two samples I just posted will replace the target element or attribute, they do not create anything new. If y is really an element in the source,  but you treat it as an attribute in the modify statement, then it will probably create the attribute for you because that is what you are telling it to do.

Comment: Just a T-SQL convention for making a string into unicode...which xml inherently is.

Comment: I understand your solution and it does work. However, it's still not doing what I want. It still creates it's own separate xml code. I don't want that. I want it to update the existing xml code from an existing column. I also added more code to the original to hopefully clarify what I'm doing. I want to see the first query updated with the "replace value of...", not a separate one.

Comment: Look at the original question and I added a paragraph that maybe explains it better.

Comment: Sure. I was using an xml snippet to demonstrate the correct syntax. Now simply apply that syntax to a table column. So your statement will be something like `UPDATE MyTable SET XmlColumn.modify('replace...');`

Comment: @Question_Guy I've added an additional example that updates a table with an xml column instead of an ad-hoc xml snippet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51615/discussion-between-question-guy-and-mdisibio)

Comment: `Cannot call methods on ntext.` is what I get

Comment: Sorry...my workplace has filtering in place that blocks any chat! Stupid...I know...

Comment: No worries. I just did it because it was suggested. But I did post my error now above your last comment

Comment: So is your xml column __typed__ as xml, or is it an ntext column with xml content?

Comment: It is an ntext column with xml content

Comment: @Question_Guy You can't use `modify()` on an ntext column. Casting will not help.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I just kind of figured that out. But thanks. So what should I do?

Comment: @mdisibio Look at my current issue on the original question please. I'm trying to insert an element into the xml file but get the given error.

Comment: nevermind. figured it out, I had an unnecessary `/` at the end